Dockerfile - how to echo to a file?
I am trying to create a bash script in dockerfile, but when I try to run it, docker says that the file does not exist. What am I doing wrong?
FROM alpine
USER root
WORKDIR /

RUN mkdir /scripts
RUN echo '#!/bin/bash\necho "test"' >> /scripts/test.sh
RUN chmod +x /scripts/test.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/scripts/test.sh"]


Maybe permissions issue? Also try to make file locally and than do COPY ./scripts/test.sh /scripts/test.sh

@Justinas thanks but of course copying from local, works just fine - but this is unfortunately not my requirement, I need to have a script within dockerfile.

The apline image has no bash installed, thus the shebang of the script is wrong. Also, the \n in the script will be written to the file literally, not as line break. Therefore, I recommend using printf instead of echo. Furthermore, we should explicitly invoke the sh shell:
FROM alpine
USER root
WORKDIR /

RUN mkdir /scripts
RUN printf '#!/bin/sh\necho "test"' >> /scripts/test.sh
RUN chmod +x /scripts/test.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/sh", "/scripts/test.sh" ]


Correct. Also if you want to keep your /script/test.sh as it is, ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/scripts/test.sh"] works too :)

Thank you but when I run your script, it still does not work - I get "exec /scripts/test.sh: no such file or directory". What is annoying, is that the build phase does not seem to report any issues - even chmod +x doesnt output any errors (I assume if file really didn't exist, that chmod would have crashed?)

@ojek You can try using ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/sh", "/scripts/test.sh" ], but for me it works as-is.
